# To Pause execution after showing UIAlertView in for loop

Tags: ios, uialertview

In my application I want to show UIAlertView in a for loop and based on choice of 'Yes', 'No'

I want to perform next steps. As UIAlertView do not pause the execution I am not able to handle this scenario. Having counter global and all will make my code more complex. So some how I want to pause the execution until user selects the alert button.

Please let me know any solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` to your `.h` file for your view controller:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
```

Then create the alert and show it when you need it:

```
- (void)showConfirmAlert
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [alert setTitle:@"Confirm"];
    [alert setMessage:@"Do you pick Yes or No?"];
    [alert setDelegate:self]; // Notice we declare the ViewController as the delegate
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

And implement the delegate method to catch the button click:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // Yes, do something
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        // No
    }
}
```

Voila, you can handle both situations.

**Edit:** If you have many alerts, declare them all as global objects so you can distinguish between each one in the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if (alertView == alertOne) { //alertOne is a globally declared UIAlertView
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            // Yes, do something
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            // No
        }
    } else if (alertView == alertTwo) { //alertTwo is a globally declared UIAlertView
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            // Yes, do something
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            // No
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Liam George Betsworth, Thanks for you reply but, I know this traditional approach. But I want to do this in loop so its not feasible for me to handle the loop condition and all.

Answer (score 0):

When you display AlertView break your loop that time and then on user choice again run the loop or further execution. By the way what do you want to achieve actually?